# Киберманкурты или кибер-манкурты?

Tags: пунктуация, слитно-дефис

Как пишется: кибер-манкурты (через дефис), киберманкурты (слитно) или кибер манкурты (раздельно)?

Answer (score 2):

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/132-def-19-18

Можно трактовать слово как *сложносокращённое* (ср. "профсоюз", поскольку нет слова "кибер" - это *сокращение* от "кибернетический"; по этой же причине *отпадает раздельное* написание). При этом слово не заимствуется полностью из одного языка ("манкурт" ранее пришло в русский из киргизского) и, соответственно, не может оказаться в словаре в результате формальной транскрипции. Тем не менее, и "словарный" подход подкрепляет слитность написания: аналогично образовано, напр., слово "*киберпространство*". Поэтому написание должно быть **слитным**, а не дефисным.

Comment: Как пишется Кибер с именем собственным Иисус? Кибериисус, Кибер-Иисус, или кибер Иисус

Answer (score 1):

[Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290247): Сложные слова с первой частью кибер- пишутся слитно.